Join 2 dict elements of list into 1 not working
I am extracting data from a list of json results from a former task, to get the vlan number based on subnet.
Using this I need a single list containing both vlans in the form of:
"nic1": ["100"], "nic1": ["200"]

I'll use this to call another API to provision a vm where I have to provide vlan information list like so:
    "network": {
        "nic0": [
            "100"
        ],
        "nic1": [
            "200"
        ]
    },

I have tried flattening and combining, but apparently I'm not doing it correctly.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Here's what I've tried:
First obtain network information from our api with using subnet as search critera and set a fact net_info:
"item": "10.20.0.0",
"json": {
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "az": "a",
            "env": "test",
       },
       "subnet": "10.20.0.0"
       "vlanNumber": 100
     }
},
"item": "10.20.1.0",
"json": {
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "az": "a",
            "env": "test",
       },
       "subnet": "10.20.1.0"
       "vlanNumber": 200
     }
}

Next I extract just the vlan number as a list using net_info.results:
- name: Set nic number and vlan facts for provision payload
  set_fact:
    Network: "{{ Network | default([]) + [{ 'nic' + nicnum|string: [item.json.data.vlanNumber | string] }] }}"
 loop: "{{ net_info.results }}"
   loop_control:
     index_var: nicnum

This gives:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "Network": [
        {
            "nic0": [
                "100"
            ]
        },
        {
            "nic1": [
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Ideally the previous step would give the desired end result, but no.
I tried to flatten Network, that no effect, looked the same as previous output.
I thought to combine at this point, but there is no common element so I created a second list with nics as a common denominator:
- name: set new list with nics and items from Network
  set_fact:
    Network2: "{{ Network2 | default([]) + [{ 'nics': [item] | join() }] }}"
  loop: "{{ Network }}"

gives:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "Network2": [
        {
            "nics": "{'nic0': ['2309']}"
        },
        {
            "nics": "{'nic1': ['2308']}"
        }
    ]
}

I tried a simple mapping, and although that got close, it includes extra curly braces and quotes on each element of the list:
- name: Try mapping
  debug:
    msg: "{{ Network2 | map(attribute='nics') }}"

gives:
TASK [provisionvms : Try mapping] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "{'nic0': ['2309']}",
        "{'nic1': ['2308']}"
    ]
}

Finally, I tried to merge (looks identical to previous task), and then I tried to combine but it complains:
- name: show network2 merged and then combined
  debug:
    #msg: "{{ Network2 | community.general.lists_mergeby('nics') }}"
    msg: "{{ Network2 | ansible.builtin.combine('nics') }}"

TASK [provisionvms : show network2 combined] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'str': \n{\"nics\": \"{'nic1': ['2308']}\"}\n\"nics\""}

I did see the zip filter and thought that looked promising but wasn't sure what the values_list would be:
- name: Try zippig Network two based on nics
  debug:
    msg: "{{ Network2(nics | zip<unsure of this>)) }}"

I feel like this should be really simple i'm just not getting it.
Thanks in advance.

You want a dict hence why are you constructing a list? In your very first task just replace with: Network: "{{ Network | default({}) | combine({ 'nic' + nicnum|string: [item.json.data.vlanNumber | string] }) }}". Vlan number will still be in a list for each nic key which I'm not even sure if needed.

Q: "Given the iteration results
  net_info.results:
    - item: 10.20.0.0
      json:
        data:
          attributes: {az: a, env: test}
          subnet: 10.20.0.0
          vlanNumber: ['100']
    - item: 10.20.1.0
      json:
        data:
          attributes: {az: a, env: test}
          subnet: 10.20.1.0
          vlanNumber: ['200']

Create the dictionary
  network:
    {
        "nic1": [
            "100"
        ],
        "nic2": [
            "200"
        ]
    }


A: Get the list of attributes vlanNumber
  vns: "{{ net_info.results | map(attribute='json.data.vlanNumber') }}"

gives
  vns:
    - ['100']
    - ['200']

Create the list of indexes
  idx: "{{ range(1, vns|length +1) }}"

gives
  idx:
  - 1
  - 2

Create the list of the dictionary keys
  nic: "{{ ['nic'] | product(idx) | map('join') }}"

gives
  nic:
  - nic1
  - nic2

Create the dictionary
  network: "{{ dict(nic|zip(vns)) }}"

gives what you want in YAML
  network:
    nic1: ['100']
    nic2: ['200']

, or in JSON
  network:
    {
        "nic1": [
            "100"
        ],
        "nic2": [
            "200"
        ]
    }



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    net_info:
      results:
        - item: 10.20.0.0
          json:
            data:
              attributes: {az: a, env: test}
              subnet: 10.20.0.0
              vlanNumber: ["100"]
        - item: 10.20.1.0
          json:
            data:
              attributes: {az: a, env: test}
              subnet: 10.20.1.0
              vlanNumber: ["200"]

    vns: "{{ net_info.results | map(attribute='json.data.vlanNumber') }}"
    idx: "{{ range(1, vns|length +1) }}"
    nic: "{{ ['nic'] | product(idx) | map('join') }}"
    network: "{{ dict(nic|zip(vns)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: net_info.results | to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: vns | to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: idx
    - debug:
        var: nic
    - debug:
        var: network | to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: network | to_nice_json


